# Custom message for push registry alert j2me

Tags: push-notification, java-me, midlet, java-wireless-toolkit

When I receive a push notification in my j2me application it shows its built-in message at start, what I want to do is to place my own message say "Do You Want to Launch App?" when a notification of invoking application is received! How to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unlikely that application developer would be allowed to do stuff like that in the real phone, and here's why.

This functionality is a part of security sensitive features (if you're interested in details, check documentation like [The Recommended Security Policy for GSM/UMTS Compliant Devices](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/maintenance/jsr118/MIDP_2.0.1_MR_addendum.pdf)).

If this would be allowed, malware applications could transform not just wording but the very meaning of a standard system message, thus tricking user into doing something wrong.

---

For an example, imagine an application doing tracking of user location, or sending paid SMS, or something similarly *sensitive* to one's privacy or budget, having mentioned message changed to:

> ### Click Yes to win million dollars.

As a phone user, the last thing I would want of my device would be to allow tricks like that.